# Does turning off the monitor drop GPU power consumption?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, power, gpu

When I manually switch one of my monitors off in a dual monitor setup does the GPU drop power consumption and stop sending a signal to the monitor?

Does it work the same way when Windows turns off the screen (via power options, the screen is set to turn off after a specified amount of inactivity).

If not, what's the best way to hibernate a display, decrease the load and power consumption of the GPU?

Comment: Unlikely because the GPU didn't turn them off.   Even if there is it's likely negilible

Comment: So, when Windows turns off the screen (blinking/yellow power light on monitor, "standby mode") then the GPU stops sending a signal to the screen right?

Comment: It's suppose to. You don't indicate what GPU you have

Comment: It's a GTX 670, but I'd also be interested in knowing how it work if Intel or AMD was the case.

Answer (score 2):

AMD GPUs starting with HD 7XXX have a feature called `ZeroCore` [which reduces the power consumption](http://www.vortez.net/articles_pages/amd_radeon_r9_270x_review,3.html) when the monitor is power off by Windows (not when you manually turn it off)

> With Southern Islands AMD is introducing ZeroCore Power, their long
>   idle power saving technology. By implementing power islands on their
>   GPUs AMD can now outright shut off most of the functional units of a
>   GPU when the GPU is going unused, leaving only the PCIe bus interface
>   and a couple other components active. By doing this AMD is able to
>   reduce their power consumption from 15W at idle to under 3W in long
>   idle, a power level low enough that in a desktop the power consumption
>   of the video card becomes trivial. So trivial in fact that with under
>   3W of heat generation AMD doesn’t even need to run the fan – ZeroCore
>   Power shuts off the fan as it’s rendered an unnecessary device that’s
>   consuming power.
>   ([Source](http://www.anandtech.com/show/5261/amd-radeon-hd-7970-review/11))